# How to slide up a view when title on top navbar is clicked

Tags: react-native

I use `react-navigation` and have custom navbar that looks like this:

```
export default class Posts extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: <Title />,
    headerRight: <Icon icon={require('../../assets/svg/search.svg')} screenToGo="Search"/>,
    headerLeft: <Icon icon={require('../../assets/svg/person-outline.svg')} screenToGo="Profile"/>,
  };
...
}
```

Here, `title` component is just a `TouchableOpacity` that should trigger a view component that I want to slide up and occupy half of the screen.
Could you advice on how to implement the feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `react-native-popup-menu`

Installation

`npm install react-native-popup-menu --save`

If you are using older RN versions check our compatibility table.
Basic Usage

Wrap your application inside `MenuProvider` and then simply use Menu component where you need it. Below you can find a simple example.

For more detailed documentation check API.

```
// your entry point
import { MenuProvider } from 'react-native-popup-menu';

export const App = () => (
  <MenuProvider>
    <YourApp />
  </MenuProvider>
);

// somewhere in your app
import {
  Menu,
  MenuOptions,
  MenuOption,
  MenuTrigger,
} from 'react-native-popup-menu';

export const YourComponent = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    <Menu>
      <MenuTrigger text='Select action' />
      <MenuOptions>
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Save`)} text='Save' />
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Delete`)} >
          <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Delete</Text>
        </MenuOption>
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Not called`)} disabled={true} text='Disabled' />
      </MenuOptions>
    </Menu>
  </View>
);
```

Hope this helps.

You're good to go!!